# JSON date converted from ASP - Need converting to Java

Tags: java, android, json

I have a slight problem with my JSON string which I have converted from ASP.NET.

The JSON string that C# has converted for me looks like this: `/Date(1338199919727)\/`

I guess it converts it into milliseconds or something, but how do I get a Java-date out of this huge integer?

I need to get the date displayed properly on my Android app (as a string in a specific format (dd-MM-yyyy : HH), that's why I need it to be in Java. Do I have to manually make some form of converter myself, and figure out how to do it? Or is there some sweet, easy way of doing this?

Comment: Android has a builtin JSON parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but how do i get a java-date out of this huge integer?

Ah, that part's easy:

```
Date dt = new Date(1338199919727L);
```

You are quite right, it's milliseconds-since-The-Epoch (Jan 1st at midnight, 1970). And Java's `Date` object [has a constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) that accepts that very value.

In general, most JSON parsers have the concept of a "reviver" function or class that you can pass to them, which will let you pre-process values as the JSON is being deserialized. I don't know Android's JSON parser well enough to know if it has one. If not (which would be a bit backward), you'd have to walk the resulting object graph looking for properties that had become strings and converting them to dates after-the fact.

Comment: If it was just that easy.

the line you posted gives follwing error:
The literal 1338199919727 of type int is out of range

edit - even if i cast the number to (long) inside the constructor, it gives the error.

Comment: @MartinHansen: Well, you won't be using a literal, will you? :-) But you're right, you'll want to convert the digits from the string into a `long` (`Long.parseLong`, probably) rather than an `int`, and pass that. I've added the required `L` to the literal above. :-)

Comment: Cheers mate! I did not know you could do that, you're a lifesaver. :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you need

```
    long Ldate = 1338199919727L;
    Date date = new Date(Ldate * 1000);
    String strdate = (String) DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yy h:mmaa", date);
```