# Does Android's JSON parser support revivers?

Tags: android, json

I was trying to usefully answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786383/json-date-converted-from-asp-need-converting-to-java), and figured that the questioner would want to do the conversion of the .Net-style JSON dates (`"/Date(######)\/"`) to dates via a [reviver](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.2), but [looking at the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) it's not clear to me that Android supports the concept of a "reviver". Does it?

Comment: At least for the `org.json` parser, since the "reviver" concept seems like it is outside the JSON spec, I would expect the answer to be "no". `JSONReader` in API Level 11 might offer more capabilities.

Comment: @CommonsWare: That bit about `JSONReader` borders on being an answer. ;-) Seems to me you could make a JSON parser that supported *a form* of generic revivification pretty easily with `JSONReader` (doing a proper reviver would be more work.) Re the other, the JSON spec (such as it is) is only about the notation. But Crockford's JSON parsers have had the reviver concept for years, and the Crockford-inspired one in the [ECMAScript5 specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.2) has it.

Comment: The reviver concept is certainly cool. However, if `json.org` doesn't cite it, I doubt their own reference implementation supports it. A quick Google search suggests that neither GSON (the basis for `JSONReader`) nor Jackson (probably the most popular third-party JSON parser that works on Android) seem to support it, though my scan was fairly casual. Hence, it is possible that the reviver concept just never made it into the common Java implementations. I'm supplying this info as a comment, not an answer, as I am just taking lightly-educated guesses -- I've never used a reviver myself.

Comment: @CommonsWare: No, I understand. I'm a bit surprised the Java versions don't have it. You probably know Crockford "invented" JSON. His own [JSON in JavaScript scripts](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/) have supported revivers for years. Just apparently not in the Java stuff.

Comment: I much prefer "On the 8th day, Douglas Crockford introduced JSON. And he saw that it was good." :-) https://twitter.com/#!/crockfordfacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would appear to be: **No**, not directly. But **yes**, you can do it (or a form of it) without too much work:

**No**, in that [`JSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), [`JSONArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html), [`JSONTokener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html), [`JSONReader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html), etc., don't seem to support the concept *directly*.

**Yes**, in that you could probably support a simple form of reviving (such as a context-free substitution of strings in a given format with corresponding `Date` objects) with little effort via [`JSONReader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html), or even (with just a little more work) create a fully-fledged reviver-enabled deserializer (complete with getting the order of things right, etc.). So not built-in, but not from scratch.